# debugging dask - failed to detect client

Tags: debugging, dask, dask-distributed

My `dask` `groupby` script is failing (`Memory Error`) so I set off to debug the script. I'm running on a stand-alone computer .
I've updated the `logging` in the `config.yaml` file with
`logging:
  distributed: debug
  bokeh: debug
  tornado: info`

I'm running the [dask distributed example computation](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web.html#example-computation) with the following updates:

```
from distributed import LocalCluster  
c=LocalCluster()
```

and an updated script with the `range` amended to `range(10000)` .

While the script runs (and successfully completes) I see the following logs in the  `Jupyter Notebook` which  repeats itself until the script completes.

> bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - [pid 3088] 0 clients connected
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - [pid 3088]   /system has 0 sessions
>   with 0 unused bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - [pid 3088]   /stealing
>   has 0 sessions with 0 unused bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - [pid 3088]
>   /workers has 0 sessions with 0 unused bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   [pid 3088]   /events has 0 sessions with 0 unused bokeh.server.tornado
>   - DEBUG - [pid 3088]   /counters has 0 sessions with 0 unused bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - [pid 3088]   /tasks has 0 sessions with
>   0 unused bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - [pid 3088]   /status has 0
>   sessions with 0 unused

Why don't I see any workers that are running?

I get the following log  when running the `c = LocalCluster()`

> bokeh.server.server - INFO - Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.4
>   bokeh.server.server - WARNING - Host wildcard '*' can expose the
>   application to HTTP host header attacks. Host wildcard should only be
>   used for testing purpose. bokeh.server.server - WARNING - Host
>   wildcard '*' can expose the application to HTTP host header attacks.
>   Host wildcard should only be used for testing purpose.
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - Allowed Host headers: ['*']
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - These host origins can connect to the
>   websocket: ['*'] bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - Patterns are:
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -   [('/system/?', bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/system/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/system/ws', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/system/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/system/autoload.js', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/system/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/stealing/?', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/stealing/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/stealing/ws', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/stealing/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/stealing/autoload.js', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/stealing/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/workers/?', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/workers/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/workers/ws', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/workers/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/workers/autoload.js', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/workers/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/events/?', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/events/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/events/ws', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/events/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/events/autoload.js', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/events/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/counters/?', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/counters/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/counters/ws', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/counters/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/counters/autoload.js', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/counters/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG
>   -    ('/tasks/?', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/tasks/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - 
>   ('/tasks/ws', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/tasks/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - 
>   ('/tasks/autoload.js', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/tasks/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG - 
>   ('/status/?', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/status/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/status/ws', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/status/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/status/autoload.js', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     ,
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     {'application_context':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'bokeh_websocket_path': '/status/ws'}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   ('/?', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     , bokeh.server.tornado -
>   DEBUG -     {'applications': {'/counters':
>   , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   '/events': , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   '/status': , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   '/stealing': , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   '/system': , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   '/tasks': , bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   '/workers': }, bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -
>   'prefix': '', bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -      'use_redirect':
>   True}), bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -    ('/static/(.*)',
>   bokeh.server.tornado - DEBUG -     )]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging messages that you're seeing are from the Bokeh diagnostic dashboard.  They're essentially saying that no one is looking at the diagnostic webpage.  You might want to decrease the verbosity of your Bokeh logging.  I don't think that these messages concern you.

Debug level logging is almost always too verbose for any user.  It tends to be used by developers when debugging.

Comment: Thx for the clarification - Now it is clear. I was on the quest to trying to understand why I'm not able to see the web dashboard and thought that the debugging will assist. I still have no visibility to the dashboard....

Comment: Update Bokeh to >= 0.12.6.  Tornado and Bokeh 0.12.4 have a known incompatibility issue.